# BIO to EVP_PKEY (Public and Private)

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I am stuck on how to convert a BIO* to its EVP_PKEY counterparts so that i can later use it in encryption. Currently my keygen routine looks like this:

```
bool SecureCrypto::GenerateRSAKeys()
{
    BIGNUM* BigNum = nullptr;
    BIGNUM* BigNum2 = nullptr;
    BigNum = BN_new();
    if (BN_set_word(BigNum, RSA_F4) <= 0)
        return false;

    BigNum2 = BN_new();
    if (BN_set_word(BigNum2, RSA_F4) <= 0)
        return false;

    m_ServerKeyPair = RSA_new();
    m_ClientKeyPair = RSA_new();
    RSA_generate_key_ex(m_ServerKeyPair,RSA_KeyLen, BigNum, NULL);
    RSA_generate_key_ex(m_ClientKeyPair,RSA_KeyLen, BigNum2, NULL);

    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(m_ServerPublicKeyBIO, m_ServerKeyPair);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(m_ServerPrivateKeyBIO,  
    m_ServerKeyPair,EVP_aes_256_cbc(), (unsigned char*)RSA_PrivKeyPassPhrase.c_str(),   
    RSA_PrivKeyPassPhrase.size(), NULL, NULL);

    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(m_ClientPublicBIO, m_ClientKeyPair);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(m_ClientPrivateBIO, m_ClientKeyPair, EVP_aes_256_cbc(),    
    (unsigned char*)RSA_PrivKeyPassPhrase.c_str(), RSA_PrivKeyPassPhrase.size(), NULL,  
    NULL);

    BN_free(BigNum);
    BN_free(BigNum2);
    return true;
}
```

Later on i need to convert m_ServerPrivateKeyBIO into a EVP_PKEY for use with EVP_SealInit.
I only know of PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(), but everytime i call it i get a return value of 0 (fail).I call it as such:

```
PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(m_ServerPrivateKeyBIO, NULL, NULL, "Enc Key");
```

I plan on the server doing encryption with its private key then sending data to client and client decrypting it with the servers public key, i would appreciate any help here, as the OpenSSL docs don't help at all.

P.S i have client and server keys being generated for a test, obviously this would not happen in final code.

Comment: *"how to convert a BIO* to its EVP_PKEY counterparts ..."* - they are *not* related, so you can't convert between them. A `BIO` is used for input/output. `EVP_PKEY` is a key abstraction, and it holds key material.

Comment: *"I plan on the server doing encryption with its private key..."* - encryption with a private key is not a valid crypto operation. Do you mean a Signature Scheme with Recovery?

Comment: Perhaps you should use SSL/TLS with a hardened the channel. Harden the channel by removing weak/wounded/broken protocols and ciphers. Harden it further by pinning the server's public key in the client. See, for example, [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki; and [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) on OWASP.

Comment: @jww I thought private key encryption would act a signing and obscurity in one step, all i really need is signing so i will research that. I also switched how i generate keys so i am now able to hold my key information in EVP_PKEYS, i use the EVP_PKEY_keygen for this is this the most correct way?

Comment: I attempted Signing but again got stuck, my new thread is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954979/openssl-fails-at-evp-verifyfinal for anything with issues in the futre