# OpenSSL Fails at EVP_VerifyFinal

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

After a few days of scouring the internet and openssl docs i've hit a wall. I'm attempting to sign a message with a private key, and then verify the authenticity of the message with a public key.

Key Generation Code:

```
    //Generate RSA Keys
    EVP_PKEY_CTX* KeyCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
    if (KeyCtx == nullptr)
        return false;

    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(KeyCtx) <= 0)
        return false;

    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(KeyCtx, RSA_KeyLen) <= 0)
        return false;

    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(KeyCtx, &m_ServerKeyPair) <= 0)
        return false;

    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(KeyCtx, &m_ClientKeyPair) <= 0)
        return false;

    //Write Keys to EVP_PKEYS for actual internal encryption,BIO mem is wiped after read so we need a new copy
    PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(KeyToPrivBio(m_ServerKeyPair), &m_ServerPrivateKey, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(KeyToPubBio(m_ServerKeyPair), &m_ServerPublicKey, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(KeyToPrivBio(m_ClientKeyPair), &m_ClientPrivateKey, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(KeyToPubBio(m_ClientKeyPair), &m_ClientPublicKey, NULL, NULL);
```

RSA Sign:

```
bool SecureCrypto::RSASign(const unsigned char* Msg, size_t MsgLen,unsigned char** EncMsg, size_t& MsgLenEnc)
{
    EVP_PKEY_size(m_ServerPrivateKey);
    *EncMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(m_ServerPrivateKey));

    if (EVP_SignInit_ex(m_RSASignCtx, EVP_sha1(), 0) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Init\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_SignUpdate(m_RSASignCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Update\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_SignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, *EncMsg, &MsgLenEnc, m_ServerPrivateKey) <=0)
    {
        printf("Failed Final Sign\n");
        return false;
    }
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(m_RSASignCtx);

    return true;
}
```

RSA Verify:

```
bool SecureCrypto::RSAVerifySignature(const unsigned char* MsgHash, size_t MsgHashLen,unsigned char* Msg, size_t MsgLen)
{
    if (EVP_VerifyInit(m_RSAVerifyCtx, EVP_sha1()) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Verify Init\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_VerifyUpdate(m_RSAVerifyCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Verify \n");
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_VerifyFinal(m_RSAVerifyCtx, MsgHash, MsgHashLen, m_ServerPublicKey)<=0);
    {
        printf("Failed Final Verify %s\n",ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(),NULL));
        return false;
    }
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(m_RSAVerifyCtx);
    return true;
}
```

Key Generation is successful, and i have viewed the keys it creates they appear to be valid and are in the format `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`, some large prime, `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`. Sign appears to be successful and returns a hash. EVP_Verify fails on the last step EVP_VerifyFinal, ERR_error_string reports this:

```
error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

Which is obviously not helpful, can someone please point out what i may be doing wrong. This is my first dive into openssl, so there may be some big issues here.

Comment: If `EVP_VerifyFinal()` returns 0, then that means the signature verification failed, and there will be no error code set because that's the normal operation of the function.  You should handle the cases of less than 0 and equal to 0 separately.

Comment: Ok i will change that, but the big issue here is why its failing

Comment: `EVP_Sign` and `EVP_Verify` are deprecated and should not be used. You should use `EVP_DigestSign` now. *"After a few days of scouring the internet and openssl docs..."* - You should also visit [EVP Signing and Verifying](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying). That's an official OpenSSL sample. It should work with copy/paste. Or visit one of the sample apps in `<openssl dir>/apps`. before the wiki samples, we used to have to grep the apps directory.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to JWW and indiv i was able to solve my problem, it was an issue with me using older API's, and improper return checking. Solution:

```
bool SecureCrypto::RSASign(const unsigned char* Msg, size_t MsgLen,unsigned char** EncMsg, size_t* MsgLenEnc)
{
    if (EVP_DigestSignInit(m_RSASignCtx,NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL,m_ServerPrivateKey) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Init\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(m_RSASignCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Update\n");
        return false;
    }

    //Get Hash Size
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, NULL,MsgLenEnc) <=0)
    {
        printf("Failed Final Sign\n");
        return false;
    }

    //Allocate Space for hash
    *EncMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(*MsgLenEnc);
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, *EncMsg, MsgLenEnc) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Final Sign 1\n");
        return false;
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(m_RSASignCtx);

    return true;
}

bool SecureCrypto::RSAVerifySignature(const unsigned char* MsgHash, size_t MsgHashLen,unsigned char* Msg, size_t MsgLen,bool* Authentic)
{
    if (EVP_DigestVerifyInit(m_RSAVerifyCtx,NULL, EVP_sha256(),NULL,m_ServerPrivateKey) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Verify Init\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(m_RSAVerifyCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed Verify \n");
        return false;
    }

    int AuthStatus = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(m_RSAVerifyCtx, (unsigned char*)MsgHash, MsgHashLen);

    if (AuthStatus==1)
    {
        //Message Authentic
        *Authentic = true;
        EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(m_RSAVerifyCtx);
        return true;
    } else if(AuthStatus==0){
        //Message Not Authentic
        *Authentic = false;
        EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(m_RSAVerifyCtx);
        return true; //Still did our job correctly
    } else{
        printf("Error\n");
        *Authentic = false;
        EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(m_RSAVerifyCtx);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I cant believe i missed such an obvious example, thanks for you help guys, sorry i looked so stupid lol.

Comment: In this example you use `m_ServerPrivateKey` in the RSAVerifySignature. Isn't the point of RSAVerification that you can verify the signature with the message, hash and *public* key? Why do you use the private key here?

Comment: It was a copy and paste fail from my test to this site. You are exactly right it should use the servers public key. My final openssl wrapper can be viewed here: https://github.com/stevemk14ebr/OpenSSL_Wrapper/blob/master/Secure%20Crypto/Crypto.cpp